# Add two price for same item at codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cart

i want to add two price for same item in codeigniter. But there is available for add only one price at codeigniter cart function. i need to insert INR price and USD price separate. how can i do this ? i stuck in this past 8 hours , Please clear me any one

The Normal code for add item at cart

```
$proid=$this->input->post('pid');
                $this->db->where('pid',$pid);
                $data=$this->db->get('product')->result();
                foreach ($data as $pro)
                {
                    $proname=$pro->pro_name;
                    $salb1=$pro->s1price;
                    $salb2=$pro->s2price;
                    $salb3=$pro->s3price;
                    $salb4=$pro->s4price;
                    $proimg=$pro->image_name;
                    $nwt=$pro->case_netweight;
                    $gwt=$pro->case_grossweight;
                    $cbm=$pro->cbm;
                }

                switch ($this->session->userdata('buser_slab'))
                {
                    case 1:
                        $price = $salb1;
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        $price = $salb2;
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        $price = $salb3;
                    break;
                    case 4:
                        $price = $salb4;
                    break;
                }

                $propriceinr =round($price + round(($price * $this->session->userdata('margin'))/100,2));   


                $dat = array(
               'id'      => $pid,
               'qty'     => 1,
               'price'   => $propriceinr,
               'name'    => $proname,
               'options' => array('cbm' => $cbm, 'nwt' => $nwt,'gwt'=>$gwt,'image' => $proimg ,'price'=>$price)
            );              
                $this->cart->insert($dat);
```

Comment: Use a helper function in view to convert the price to the needed currency. Helper function can read conversion rate from any database if needed.

Comment: please give me some example for this

Comment: I am doing similar thing for formatting the dates to user prefered format in my website. For example create a helper function called convertCurrencyValue($amount,$currency_from,$currency_to) in a helper file called 'currency.php'. In that function echo the converted value. Then in view you can use it to display the currency value after loading the helper file in the controller.